# How to maintain multiple lists in CSV file and how to read it using python

Tags: python, automated-tests

I am running test cases using python. For my scenarios I need to have multiple lists in CSV file and read them one by one. For now I am working with single list per CSV file and because of that I am having lot of csv files. Could you pls help on this?

my desired CSV file is like below containing more then one list:

```
bundleParentId;id;itemType;itemNo;requiredQty;unitOfMeasure
 ;2;ART;20318823;2;Piece
 ;3;ART;00258882;2;Piece
 ;4;ART;40401840;2;Piece

bundleParentId;id;itemType;itemNo;requiredQty;unitOfMeasure
 ;2;ART;20318823;2;Piece

bundleParentId;id;itemType;itemNo;requiredQty;unitOfMeasure
 ;2;ART;20565823;2;Piece
 ;3;ART;00259876;2;Piece

bundleParentId;id;itemType;itemNo;requiredQty;unitOfMeasure
 ;2;ART;67543898;2;Piece
 ;3;ART;13432343;2;Piece
 ;4;ART;00972444;2;Piece
 ;5;ART;00258882;2;Piece
 ;6;ART;40401840;2;Piece
```

Comment: what do you meant by multiple lists in csv ? do you wish to write multiple lines in csv ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use something like [TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). TinyDB allows you to make a simple database structure that works like a flat dictionary. A TinyDB object can handle multiple databases all stored in a single flat(ish) JSON file.

Each row in the DB is aware of it's content and can be easily queried, deleted and upserted.

It's as simple as this to create, insert a record and query a DB:

```
>>> from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
>>> db = TinyDB('path/to/db.json')
>>> User = Query()
>>> db.insert({'name': 'John', 'age': 22})
>>> db.search(User.name == 'John')
[{'name': 'John', 'age': 22}]
```

Comment: Could you pls help me to read the above csv file contents in to multiple lists

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but you could simple run each entry into a TinyDB using the code sample above. Wrap your list in a for loop and feed them into the database.